# Can kubectl delete environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl

Here I can update the envs through `kubectl patch`, then is there any method that can delete envs except re-deploy a `deployment.yaml`?

```
$ kubectl patch deployment demo-deployment -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name": "demo-deployment","env":[{"name":"foo","value":"bar"}]}]}}}}'
deployment.extensions "demo-deployment" patched
```

Can I delete the env "foo" through command line not using a re-deploy on the whole deployment?

Comment: You want to unset the environment variable from the perspective of the running process without restarting the processes? That’s not possible via Kubernetes resource update.

Comment: hi Amit，the process restarting is acceptable. I mean can we use ```kubectl patch``` to unset/delete the env? Thanks!

Comment: I see. If you do `kubectl patch`, the deployment will effectively re-deploy, you just don't want to have to run `kubectl apply -f dep.yaml` with the whole deployment YAML, is that right?

Comment: If you manually change things using `kubectl patch`, the copy of the YAML files you've checked into source control won't match what you actually have deployed.  Why don't you want to do `kubectl apply`?

Answer (score 37):

This is coming late but for newcomers, you can use the following `kubectl` command to remove an existing env variable from a deployment

```
kubectl set env deployment/DEPLOYMENT_NAME  VARIABLE_NAME-
```

Do not omit the hyphen (`-`) at the end

Comment: to get the deployments names `kubectl get deployments -n <namespace>`, and to see the variables declared in the deployment `kubectl describe deployment <deployment name> -n <namespace>`

Comment: simple & easy solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with redeployment then follow the below steps

1. Create configmap and include your environment variables
2. Load env variables from configmap in the deployment

```
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
  name: app-config
```

3. If you want to delete env variable then remove those key-value pairs from configmap
4. It will cause redeployment. You can also delete the pod from corresponding deployment

Answer (score 1):

Consider that `containers` is an array inside an object. Arrays can only be fetched by their `index`, as opposed to objects which can be fetched via key value pairs. See reference [here](https://www.w3schools.in/json/json-syntax/).  So there is a workaround for using `index`.

Here you have `env` that are placed into the `container`:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: Hello from the environment
    - name: DSADASD
      value: asdsad
```

Here you have a command to remove the anv using `index`:

```
kubectl patch deployments asd  --type=json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/1"}]
```

And the result:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: Hello from the environment
```

This will still however restart your pod. 
Hope that helps!